# Modifying div from elements in other div

Tags: html, css

I need assistance with changing css of div on hover event. My code:

```html
<div class = "container-main">
 <div class = "container-inner">
  <ul class = "list">
   <li>Option 1</li>
   <li>Option 2</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div class = "container1">
 <p>Container text</p>
</div>

<div class = "container2">
 <p>Container text</p>
</div>
```

I need to be able to change classes container1 and container2 when hovering on ul or li in the main container. I only know how to change it with sibling containers but that's not what I need.

`.container-main:hover + .container1 {background:red;}`

Would appreciate any help in achieving this. Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking for exactly? if you hover on .container-main you want the bg colour of .container1 to change to red, is that all?

Comment: No, I know I can do that. I'd like to change .container1 after hovering on ul or li in main container

Comment: It's not possible with CSS. I've added a solution with javascript that should be pretty easy to understand. I chose vanilla JS since you haven't mentioned jquery as a possibility. If jquery is an option let me know and I can edit my response to include that option too.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, based on your markup heirarchy, what you're looking for isn't possible with just CSS. You can do this pretty simply with javascript though. Here's an example that will add a background-color to `.container1` when you hover `.container-main ul`:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.container-main ul')
const container1 = document.querySelector('.container1')

list.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => container1.classList.add('red'))
list.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => container1.classList.remove('red'))
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container-main">
    <div class = "container-inner">
        <ul class = "list">
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "container1">
    <p>Container text</p>
</div>

<div class = "container2">
    <p>Container text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want? 
jQuery solution:

```
$( ".container-main li" ).hover(
    function() {
        //do something when hovering 
    }, function() {
        //do something after hovering 
        $(".container1").css("background", "red");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers everyone. I was just unsure whether it was possible or not, I'll try to rearrange my div heirarchy. I know it can be done with jQuery but I have a task where I only need to use CSS without any programming languages. 
Once again, thanks a lot. I got a better idea of what needs to be changed.

Comment: Yeah, if Javascript isn't a possibility you'll need to adjust your markup. You're on the right track with the sibling selector. Also, answer posts on SO should be reserved for answers to the original question. This comment would be more appropriate as a comment to the original post, or an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think css alone can do this.
Do you have access to jquery?
https://jsfiddle.net/ifinto/o2gxgz9r/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container-main li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).hover(
      function() {
        div = ".container" + (index + 1);
        console.log("in_" + div);
        $(div).css("background-color", "red")
      },
      function() {
        div = ".container" + (index + 1);
        console.log("out_" + div);
        $(div).css("background-color", "white");
      });
  })
```